# JAVA having troubles with ButtonGroup and .values()

Tags: java

First time poster, long time lurker.

I'm having troubles with the following piece of code!
What it's supposed to do is generate 2 radio buttons and then cleverly decide which one to activate when opening a window.

There's two parts to this, a CarcolorButtonModel that extends JtoggleButton.ToggleButtonModel, and a CarcolorButtonGroup, this extends ButtonGroup.
The method I'm having trouble with is the following:

```
public class CarcolorButtonGroup extends ButtonGroup
{

    public void setValue(color c)
    {
        for(AbstractButton b: getElements())
        {
            stuff
        }
    ...
```

No matter what I do it won't run. Even .values() isn't helping.
Any ideas?

edit follow-ups:

The error I'm currently getting is: "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable". The other solution I've tried is to declare the enumeration and array before the method, i.e.:

```
Enumeration<AbstractButton> e = getElements();
AbstractButton[] ara = e.values();
```

It doesn't like this, however, it claims that "values() is undefined for the type Enumeration.

To be clear, the method is supposed to cycle through each button and see if its saved color matches up with c. The code fails at the for loop for the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you write something close to a [MCVE]?

Comment: The error I'm currently getting is:
"Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable".

The other solution I've tried is to declare the enumeration and array before the method, i.e.:

Enumeration<AbstractButton> e = getElements();
AbstractButton[] ara = e.values();

It doesn't like this, however, it claims that
"values() is undefined for the type Enumeration<AbstractButton>"

Comment: Use a `List` not an `Enumeration`. That class is outdated by `Iterator`, and isn't compatible with a for-each loop.

Comment: How would that work and is it compatible with getElements()?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, .values() simply doesn't work in this case, using .nextElement() in a hasmoreElements() controlled while loop sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an `Enumeration` to something that is `Iterable` by using [`Collections.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list-java.util.Enumeration-).

> Returns an array list containing the elements returned by the specified enumeration in the order they are returned by the enumeration. This method provides interoperability between legacy APIs that return enumerations and new APIs that require collections.

```
for (AbstractButton b : Collections.list(getElements())) {
    // stuff
}
```